# How to do login using volley?

Tags: java, android-volley

I am new in Java (android studio).

I tried to use Volley to do Post http request.

My objective is to make login.

I did some research, and find out the way to send form-data is something like these.

But I am lost.

Here is my full code.

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.homesweethome"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1"

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.homesweethome">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.homesweethome;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    /* Define the UI elements */
    private EditText eName;
    private EditText ePassword;
    private TextView eAttemptsInfo;
    private Button eLogin;

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private String url = "https://apisguatukang.spatialworks.com.my/login";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    String userName = "";
    String userPassword = "";



    boolean isValid = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Bind the XML views to Java Code Elements */
        eName = findViewById(R.id.idUsername);
        ePassword = findViewById(R.id.idPassword);
        eLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        /* Describe the logic when the login button is clicked */
        eLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /* Obtain user inputs */
                userName = eName.getText().toString();
                userPassword = ePassword.getText().toString();


                /* Check if the user inputs are empty */
                if(userName.isEmpty() || userPassword.isEmpty())
                {
                    /* Display a message toast to user to enter the details */
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter name and password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else {

                    validate(userName, userPassword);
                    
                   

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /* Validate the credentials */
    private void validate(final String userName, final String userPassword)
    {
          mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error);
                    }
                }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username",userName.trim());
                params.put("password",userPassword.trim());
                Log.i(TAG, "getParams: "+ params);
                return params;
            }

        };

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

The Post Request using Postman

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my following source code

```
//Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.d("Response",""+response);
                        //If we are getting success from server
                        if (response.equals("success")) {
                            //Creating a shared preference

                            SharedPreferences sp = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putString(Constant.ROLL_SHARED_PREF, roll);

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.apply();

                            //Starting Home activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }




                        else if(response.equals("failure")) {
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Roll or Password is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else {
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid user cell or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //You can handle error here if you want

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "There is an error !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put(Constant.KEY_ROLL, roll);
                params.put(Constant.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I took this source code from my `git repository`
Maybe if you visit the following link than you will understand it more properly.

[Volley login activity](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/StudentInformation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/studentinformation3/LoginActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

**You would need to use this string request method to post your request for login where you need to map up your parameters with the request.
The sample code is shown below with certain comment where you would need to change. Hope it would help.**

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, //your url here// , response -> {
    
                        if(response != null){

                             /////do something here/////
    
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
    
                    }, error -> {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        
                    }) {
                        //// pass parameters id and password here////
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("email", id.getText().toString().trim());
                            map.put("password", pass.getText().toString().trim());
                            return map;
                        }
                    };
    
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                    queue.add(request);
```

Comment: please add explanation to your answer. Code-only answer is very much discouraged in stackoverflow.

Comment: @EmonHossainMunna, I modified  my MainActivity.java code as you highlight it. But still I cannot log the response. Why I did wrong? You may look at my MainActivity.java above.

Comment: @SafiahNadiah This method will be called when you would hit the login button from login activity. it means you need to call this method under your LoginButton.setOnClickListener method.